# Grails - Bootstrap - null pointers instead of services

Tags: grails

I'd like to use data generator at init in my application. It works fine when create objects using .save() method, but it doesn't work when I want to use dedicated services, because of null pointers instead of injected services. That's my code:

I have defined DataGenerator bean inside conf/spring

```
beans = {
    dataGenerator(DataGenerator)
}
```

My `Bootstrap.groovy` looks like:

```
class BootStrap {
  def dataGenerator
  def init = { servletContext ->
    dataGenerator.generateData()
  }
}
```

In `DataGenerator' I have:

```
class DataGenerator{
    BookService bookService

    def generateData() {
        log.info("Generating books")
        createBooks()
    }

    def createBooks(){
        (1..40).each() {
            CreateBookCommand command = new CreateBookCommand()
            /* some command populate code*/
            bookService.create(command);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, that I cannot invoke `create()` method, because `bookService` is always `null`

BookService is simple grails service with some dependencies, of course placed in `grails-app/services`

```
class BookService {    
    UserService userService
    SpringSecurityService springSecurityService

    def create(CreateBookCommand command){
        Book book = new Book()
        command.bindTo(book)
        book.save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
    }
    /*some other methods*/

}
```

Could you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: It seems the service in your DataGenerator is not injected.  But it can be injected if you place it inside Bootstrap.  Why not pass the service from bootstrap to DataGenerator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in resources.groovy

```
beans = {
 dataGenerator(DataGenerator) { bean ->
   bean.autowire = 'byName'
  }
}
```

Comment: why wasn't the bean auto injected by name by default by Grails?

Answer (score 1):

I assume `DataGenrator` being a class outside the grails artifact (that is: placed in `src/groovy`), you can refer the already available service class in the context as:

```
beans = {
    dataGenerator(DataGenerator){
        bookService = ref('bookService')
    }
}
```

or try autowiring `byName` as mentioned by @sudhir.